# How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am implementing a cart in Xamarin.Forms. In my cart page there is a `ListView` with data. Each of the cell contains a button to select the count of *item* and *amount*. In the cart view there is a grand total label.

My problem is the grand total is not updating while the number picker changes. The calculation method is called upon item adding view cell. I know that i need to implement `INotifyProperty` for this, but I'm unsure of how to do it.

I have a base view model which inherits `INotifyProperty` that contains an event.

```
 public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double  _price;
    public double Price
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _price; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            _price = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Price");}
        } 

 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
 {
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
     {
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
 }
```

**View model**

```
    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        App.Instance.ViewModel = this;
        TempList = TempList ?? new ObservableCollection<cm_items>();
        this.Title = AppResources.AppResource.Cart_menu_title;
        this.Price = CartCell.price;
    }
```

Comment: Please have a look at this sample https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Hanselman.Forms. In this repository you can find implementation of `MVVM` pattern and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As a design methodology, its better to implement MVVM as a subclass and implement it to your `ViewModel`.

**Sample Implementation:**

```
public class ObservableProperty : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**I also strongly suggest implementing ICommand as a Dictionary structure like:**

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : ObservableProperty
{
    public Dictionary<string,ICommand> Commands { get; protected set; }

    public ViewModelBase()
    {
        Commands = new Dictionary<string,ICommand>();
    }
}
```

**So all todo in your ViewModel is just inherit the ViewModelBase class and use it**

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region fields
    string userName;
    string password;
    #endregion

    #region properties
    public string UserName 
    {
         get {return userName;}
        set 
        {
            userName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
        }
     }

    public string Password 
    {
        get{return password;}
        set
        {
            password = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region ctor
    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        //Add Commands
        Commands.Add("Login", new Command(CmdLogin));
    }
    #endregion


    #region UI methods

    private void CmdLogin()
    {
        // do your login jobs here
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Finally: Xaml Usage:**

```
<Entry Placeholder="Username"  Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
<Entry Placeholder="Password" Text="{Binding Password}" IsPassword="True"/>
<Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding Commands[Login]}"/>
```

Comment: I know this was 5 years ago but for anyone finding this, I'm not sure it's good practice to implement the ICommand in this way using a dictionary as it breaks Compile Time Bindings which in my opinion is a valuable tool.

Comment: @henda79 What would be your recommended solution with this change?

Comment: @RandomNumberFun, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @henda79 Just trying to figure out best practices regarding your comment.

Comment: Don't use hardcoded name in the propertychanged. Use nameof() instead like this: nameof(UserName).
This way, you can rename more easily and make sure that there are no typos in your names.

Comment: [jauhenka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32800248/199364) shows a more convenient form of this. Setter is a single line, and property name does not have to be supplied.

Answer (score 6):

For example try this view model:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetPropertyValue<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (value == null ? field != null : !value.Equals(field))
        {
            field = value;

            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and in inherited classes use it like this:

```
    private int myProperty;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return this.myProperty; }
        set { this.SetPropertyValue(ref this.myProperty, value); }
    }
```

Comment: its ok now i have resolved  the problem was in my view ,i missed to add    BindingContext  in view . But now i am facing  other problem same as like this. I have " + " button in list view while i add an item in to cart the image must change to " - " .  when i delete an item from my cart the image again change to " + " . I hope here also i need i notify but how to implement here . I have a Boolean property now, my logic is this : change the Boolean value while adding  and removing but i don't know how to change the image to the button ,

Comment: Oh, here everything is even more interesting. You should add a converter and use it like this:

<Image 
Source="{Binding YourProperty, Converter={m:UxBoolConvert OnTrue='YourPlusIcon.png', OnFalse='YourMinusIcon.png'}}" />

But this is actually a different question.

Comment: can you give me an example so i can check it out i am using C# for design

Comment: The example of UxBoolConvert doesn't fit in an answer comment, too many characters. Create a separate question and post a link here, I'll put it in an answer.

Answer (score 6):

When I started Xamarin coding, the MVVM was a bit confusing until I discovered that the PropertyChangedEvent on the ViewModel fired off a signal to the View (ContentPage), and updated the Label/textbox/etc.

For those looking for the 'latest and greatest'... Here's some revised code:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and on your property Setter:

```
public string SomeProperty
{
    get { return _somProperty; }
    set
    {
       _someProperty= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Nice?  No?  Saves having to pass the property name each time!

Comment: [jauhenka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32800248/199364) shows a more convenient form of this. Setter can be done in one line instead of two.