# xamarin forms listview onpropertychanged

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have this InfiniteScrollCollection listview that is taking the data from a web API and I have an onpropertychanged method, I need to make the items in the listview update instantly when I change a property

```
       public partial class AddOrderPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
     public InfiniteScrollCollection<Sales_Order_Items> Items { get; }
            public AddOrderPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
      Items = new InfiniteScrollCollection<Sales_Order_Items>
                {
                    OnLoadMore = async () =>
                    {
                        IsBusy = true;
                        grid.IsVisible = true;
                        // load the next page
                        //_dataService.setitemsDB();
                        var page = Items.Count / PageSize;
                        // var items = await GetItemsAsync(page, PageSize);
                        var items = await GetItemsAsync(selectedcategorycode, ++index, searching.Text);
                        //Console.WriteLine(items);
                        IsBusy = false;
                        grid.IsVisible = false;
                        // return the items that need to be added
                        return items;
                    },
                    OnCanLoadMore = () =>
                    {
                        return newfilteredlist.Count > 0;
                    }
                };
}
```

and this is the onpropertychanged method

```
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

I'm new to propertychanged thing, so where and how should I call the function for my listview to update instantly?

Class Sales_Order_Items:

```
 public class Sales_Order_Items
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Item_Code { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string Price_List_Code { get; set; }
        public string CURRENCY_CODE { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public string Uom_Code { get; set; }
        public string Client_Code { get; set; }
        public double return_price { get; set; }
        public string Tax_Code { get; set; }
        public double Tax { get; set; }
        public string CURRENCY_SYMBOL { get; set; }
        public double Default_Discount { get; set; }
        public int item_order { get; set; }
        public int distribution_type { get; set; }
        public string Client_Name { get; set; }
        public string family { get; set; }
        public double converted_price { get; set; }
        public double converted_return_price { get; set; }
        public double converted_tax { get; set; }
        public double converted_discount { get; set; }
        public string converted_currency_code { get; set; }
        public string converted_currency_symbol { get; set; }
        public double stock_quantity { get; set; }
        public string expiry_date { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public int requested_quantity { get; set; }
        public int displayed_quantity { get; set; }
        public float discount { get; set; }
        public double totalprice { get; set; }
        public double totaldiscount { get; set; }
        public double totaltax { get; set; }
        public bool is_new { get; set; }
        public bool has_promotion { get; set; }
        public string last_order_item_date { get; set; }
        public string last_order_item_quantity { get; set; }
        public bool slashvisivble { get; set; }
        public bool discounted { get; set; }
        public bool promotioned { get; set; }
        public Color promotioncolor { get; set; }
        public Color newcolor { get; set; }
        public string usercode { get; set; }
        public bool istotalprice { get; set; }
        public bool isdraft { get; set; }
        public Color lineborderitemcolor { get; set; }
}
```

My Xaml Class:

```
 <ListView x:Name="orderslv"  HasUnevenRows="True"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" SeparatorVisibility="None" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
                    <ListView.Behaviors>
                        <extended:InfiniteScrollBehavior IsLoadingMore="{Binding isbusy}" />
                    </ListView.Behaviors>
                    <ListView.Header>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label TextColor="#FF0000" IsVisible="False" x:Name="error_label" Text="No items in this category" FontFamily="{StaticResource MyriadProRegularFont}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom Phone="20" Tablet="30"/>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ListView.Header>
                    <ListView.Footer>
                        <Grid Padding="6" x:Name="grid">
                            <!-- set the footer to have a zero height when invisible -->
                            <Grid.Triggers>
                                <Trigger TargetType="Grid" Property="IsVisible" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="0" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Grid.Triggers>
                            <!-- the loading content -->
                            <Label Text="Loading..." TextColor="#039BE5" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontFamily="{StaticResource MyriadProSemiBoldFont}">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom Phone="20" Tablet="30"/>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </ListView.Footer>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <customControls:ExtendedViewCell SelectedBackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                <ViewCell.View>


                                                    <controls:CustomStepper Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" OnValueChanged="CustomStepper_OnValueChanged"  Text="{Binding requested_quantity }" >
                                                    </controls:CustomStepper>
                                                    <Frame IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0" HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
                                                        <Button Text="ADD TO CART" TextColor="#039BE5" BackgroundColor="White"  Clicked="Addtocart_Clicked" Padding="5" >
                                                            <Button.FontSize>
                                                                <OnIdiom Phone="{OnPlatform Android=12,iOS=8}" Tablet="{OnPlatform Android=16,iOS=14}"/>
                                                            </Button.FontSize>
                                                            <Button.HeightRequest>
                                                                <OnIdiom Phone="34" Tablet="40"/>
                                                            </Button.HeightRequest>
                                                        </Button>
                                                    </Frame>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Frame>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </customControls:ExtendedViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

When I click the button I need to instantly update the "requested_quantity" property that is bound to the text of the customstepper, I need you to help me with the onpropertychanged method for this property and were to call it in order to make the change directly on the listview.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not completely clear what your question is. You have the list of items in your InfiniteScrollCollection. Then the property of one of those items changes and you want this change to be reflected on your page? Or do you mean that the items are not appearing in your listview or not being added when you reach the end of the list?

Comment: The items are appearing but I need the listview  to update instantly on my page. Yes as you said I need the changes to be reflected on my page

Comment: In that case could you please add the code where the property of the item is changed, and can you add the code of your XAML. One of the common misconceptions about ListViews is that since they react to changes in the List they have as their ItemsSource they must also react to changes of the properties of those items but that is not the case. You can either remove the item from the list and re-add it to the same position or (and this is better) you need to make sure the propertychanges of the item are seen by the view.

Comment: Oh and also we need to see the code of the Sales_Order_Items class

Comment: I Edited the question please check it out. I need to solve it as soon as possible, Thank you

Comment: As suspected and mentioned by Gerald Versluis in his answer the problem lies in the `Sales_Order_Items` class not implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This might be interesting to get a little more information on how to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667408/how-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged-in-xamarin-forms. This interface is what enables observation of property changes, without it other parts of your program will not be notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the object that you want to update. In this case, it seems you have implemented it on the view model (for your whole page) only. Which is very useful as well, but if you want the `Sales_Order_Items` to update, you need to implement the interface and method on that.

After that, things should start working.

Comment: Can you edit my question with code need in both the content page and the Sales_Order_Items class to make it more clear? Thank you very much