# Communicate between TabbedPages in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a question. I created a TabbedPage with 2 childs. In child1 I want to show the selected images. In child2 I have a Grid with a few images. Now I want to make the images in child2 selectable and when they get clicked, I want them to be inserted in the StackLayout in child1. I have no clue how to start, so can someone give me an example?

Here is the xaml from child1:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="MainLayout" VerticalOptions="Center">

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here is the Grid from child2

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="Good_Question.png" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Source="Excuse_Me.png" />

</Grid>
```

Can someone give me an example of how I can add an Image that is selected in a different tab to another tab in a TabbedPage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do so:

**1 way(Simple):**

Create a `public static ObservableCollection<Image> imageCollection= new ObservableCollection<Image>();` on main page.

Then On Page2 : Add the selected images inside `imageCollection` .

On Page1: Add `imageCollection.CollectionChanged += AddImageInsdeFirstPageLayout();`.
`CollectionChanged` is call whenever any element is added/removed inside `ObservableCollection`.

**2nd way(Work throuh MVVM logic & Preferred way)**:

Create a common ViewModel for all three pages(main Page & tabbed Pages).
Create a property inside it,namely,

```
public ObservableCollection<Image> _selectedImages { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Image> SelectedImages
    {
        get { return _selectedImages; }
        set
        {
            _selectedImages = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Add new elements inside this property from Page2 and access this property from Page1.
Make sure, you raise [OnPropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667408/how-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged-in-xamarin-forms)

**3rd way(i don't like this)**:
Use MessagingCenter. It's pretty simple to use.Go through this,if you want to dig more: [Xamarin.Forms MessageCnter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

Comment: And how can I know which image is new or deleted in the OnChange event?

Comment: Just redraw the page1,whenever anything happens to imageCollections .That way,you don't have to worry about anything.
Updated my answer with new option

Comment: What does "Create a common ViewModel for all three pages(main Page & tabbed Pages)" mean? Does it mean I should merge my two existing tabbed pages viewmodels into a single one?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is use a tabbed view instead of tabbed pages https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/tabbed-view/getting-started .

Use Two ListViews in both Child Tabs,  and when the Second Child tab's image is selected, get the selected item from ItemSelectedEvent and bind it to the First Child tab's listview. And if you need, you can removed the selected item from Second Tab's ListView.

AS both listviews in same page you dont have to worry about passing data between pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a MessageCenter to translate the Image Source.

google the Xamarin api to add it then all will be ok.