# Xamarin Forms "TextChanged" event to MVVM?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-4

I'm completely new to C#, Xamarin Forms and coding in general. I have tried following tutorials, And Microsofts documentation. However, there is still some things I really can't seem to get. Here I have an Entry in Xaml:

```
                                    <Entry Placeholder="CPR nummer"
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                       HeightRequest="50"
                                       MinimumHeightRequest="40"
                                       PlaceholderColor="Silver"
                                       Keyboard="Numeric"
                                       TextColor="Gray"
                                       x:Name="CPRnummer"
                                       MaxLength="11"
                                       TextChanged="CPRnummer_TextChanged"
                                       ReturnType="Go">
                            </Entry>
```

As you can see, not data binded (I just can't seem to find the right way to do it). So I have the Event for Text Changed placed in the .cs file (View):

```
       private void CPRnummer_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        Regex r = new Regex(@"^\d{6}-\d{4}$");
        Regex r2 = new Regex(@"^\d{1,6}");
        Regex r3 = new Regex(@"^\d{6}-\d{0,4}$");


        CPRnummer.Text = Regex.Replace(e.NewTextValue, "[^-0-9]", "");
        CPRAccept.IsEnabled = false;
        CPRAccept.Opacity = 0.5;


    
        try
        {
            C1 = e.OldTextValue.Length;
        }

        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            if (e.OldTextValue == null)
            {
                C1 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                C1 = e.OldTextValue.Length;
            }
        }

        if (!r.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue))
        {
            if (e.NewTextValue.Length<7&&!r2.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue))
            {
                CPRnummer.Text = Regex.Replace(e.NewTextValue, "[^0-9]", "");
            }
            
            else if (e.NewTextValue.Length==6&&r2.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue) && C1<e.NewTextValue.Length) {

                if (CPRnummer.Text.Length == 6)
                {
                    CPRnummer.Text = e.NewTextValue.Insert(6, "-");
                }
            }

            else if (e.NewTextValue.Length > 6 && !r3.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue) && C1<e.NewTextValue.Length)
            {
                CPRnummer.Text = Regex.Replace(e.NewTextValue, "[^0-9]", "");
                if (CPRnummer.Text.Length > 6)
                {
                    CPRnummer.Text = e.NewTextValue.Insert(6, "-");
                }
            }

            else if (!r.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue) && e.NewTextValue.Length == 11)
            {
                CPRnummer.Text = "";
            }

            else if (e.NewTextValue.Length == 10 && e.NewTextValue.All(char.IsDigit))
            {
                CPRnummer.Text = e.NewTextValue.Insert(6, "-");
            }

        }

        else
        {
            CPRAccept.IsEnabled = true;
            CPRAccept.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
            CPRAccept.Opacity = 1;
            CPRAccept.Focus();
        }
```

Don't mind the bad coding (I'm a total beginner). The code works well enough for me. It analyzes the input each time the user enters something in the entry field, and deletes invalid chars, and inserts a dash at the time I want it. I take advantage of the e.OldTextValue + NewValue a few times And disabling/enabling the Accept button directly with code. I do want to understand the MVVM way of doing this. As far as I can read, the way to do it is an ICommand? But how would I be able to react on "text changed" like the event listener is doing? And how would this all be setup in the ViewModel? If the entry field can be "data binded", can I still use the e.XXX methods + do the Try catch?

Comment: Entry does not have a Command that corresponds to the TextChanged event.  My personal advice would be to focus on getting your code to work and not worry so much about doing it the "right" way.   Working sloppy code is better than pretty code that does not work.  Get it working first, then *refactor* it to make it cleaner.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking here. Are you looking for an MVVM tutorial? That's an off-topic question for SO. Are you having trouble understanding how to implement data validation in a binding scenario for Xamarin? I believe we already have questions with answers on that topic here. Are you having trouble understanding how to enable/disable a button? Likewise. Please improve your question so it includes a proper [mcve] along with a detailed and clear explanation of what the code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm sorry for not being clear here. I'm having trouble understanding how I can migrate my EventHandler from View to ViewModel. As far as I can read it should be possible using  "Text="{Binding XXX, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" if implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface. If someone could provide an example using exactly that I would be very grateful.

Comment: There are lots of examples of MVVM, data binding, validation, etc. on the web, and even plenty on this very site. Did you look at any? The apology is nice, but what would be much better is an actual improvement to the question. You might start here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bxamarin%5d%20mvvm. One applicable Q&A is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667408/how-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: 1. [Behavior mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior) 2. `Text={Binding EntryTextMvvm}`, and put logic in the setter. 3. Validate the text when clicking button.

Comment: Thank you @Shaw I will try using option 1. I did find out that UpdateSourceTrigger does not exist in Xamarin Forms. At least not on Entry fields. So it's not possible to do it simple (at least what seems simple for a beginner like me). Please provide an answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "EventToCommandBehavior".

> The EventToCommandBehavior is a behavior that allows the user to invoke a Command through an event.

And two options:

1. Code one by yourself:
   Check the [official sample project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/behaviors-eventtocommandbehavior/), or [the class folder here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior/EventToCommandBehavior). Check the class in "Behaviors" folder, and need extra converters for some events in "Converters". And it is used like [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/e9792d200f56ef0260849b5ee16ed0b1c4de9352/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior/EventToCommandBehavior/HomePage.xaml#L19-L21)
2. Take from Xamarin.CommunityToolkit:
   Install [XCT NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit) for your solution and implement it like [eventtocommandbehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior).
   (Xamarin.CommunityToolkit is released by the official team and supported by the community.)

```
//sample code in xaml
<Entry ...>
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="TextChanged"
            Command="{Binding MVVMCommand}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```