# Assign color to a frame through a Binding in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, frame, background-color

I am trying to assign a color to a Frame through a Binding when doing a validation, I already tried it in several ways but it does not paint the color of the Frame

```
private Color _colorBox;
```

```
if (Resultado > margen1 && Resultado < margen2)
                    {
                        ColorBox = Color.Green;
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ColorBox = Color.Red;
                       
                    }
```

```
  public Color ColorBox
        {
            get { return _colorBox; }
            set { _colorBox = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
        }
```

```
<Frame CornerRadius="10"  HasShadow="False"  Margin="15,0,15,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="70" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding ColorBox}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use it like this?

```
public Color ColorBox
    {
        get { return _colorBox; }
        set { _colorBox = value; OnPropertyChanged("ColorBox");}
    }
```

Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667408/how-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged-in-xamarin-forms) can help you too

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was that I had it in a CollectionView and it didn't recognize it, I tried this and I was left: BackGroundColor="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DetalledeConsultaViewModel}},Path=ColorBox}"